# Selector drawable on MaterialButton android

Tags: android, material-design

I have been using the new MaterialButton class. I want different colors on the button when the user clicks the button.

I have been using selector drawables for this purpose since the very beginning, however it doesn't appear to be working on MaterialButton.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:text="@string/login"
  style="@style/Widget.Mohre.Button"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:cornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
  android:padding="@dimen/unit_large"
  android:id="@+id/loginBtn"/>

My Widget.Mohre.Button style
```

@color/textColorWhite
  @drawable/mohre_button_selector
  @style/TextAppearance.Button
  @animator/button_state_list_anim

My selector drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mohre_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mohre_button_selected" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mohre_button_normal" />
```

My individual drawables are just rectangle shapes with different colors like these

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="30dp"></corners>
    <solid android:color="#3a516a"></solid>
</shape>
```

The button doesn't take on the colors at all from the selector drawable. It just shows the default accent color of the application

Comment: Use backgroundTint instead of android:background

Comment: You cant set a drawabe selector as a android:backgroundTInt

Answer (score 3):

With the normal way (setting the selector drawable as background of the button), it won't work as expected if you are using `Theme.MaterialComponents`.

You can use `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar` as an alternative, but if you don't want to use that theme, then simply use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
................/>
```

You will get the same result as it was working with the Appcompat theme even if you are using latest Material themes!

Answer (score 3):

as explained in this medium post https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-buttons-76fa1a92ec0a we can use ColorStateList to change color or background of Button.

For me working solution for now was to set backgroundTint to null and backgroundTintMode to add like this:

```
<style name="Button.XYZ" parent="Button">
<item name="shapeAppearance">?attr/shapeAppearanceLargeComponent</item>
<item name="drawableTint">@color/ColorXYZ</item>

<!-- background drawable -->
<item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
<item name="backgroundTintMode">add</item>

<!-- background drawable -->
<item name="android:background">@drawable/XYZ</item>
<!-- Color drawable -->
<item name="android:textColor">@color/XYZ</item>
</style>
```

And also using the style in xml not in theme

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button that has a custom background (to apply `<selector>` e.g), but your theme is set up to use `Theme.MaterialComponents` (which is nowadays, 2021), you could switch the XML element in the layout to be `<android.widget.Button>` instead of `<Button>`. This should cause the Material Components for Android to ignore that element, and you can manipulate this button normally with respect to XML attributes.